# Meaning of xcos datatype dimensions

Tags: scilab, xcos

I am experiencing conflicts between xcos blocks. For example I am not able to connect a `real [-2 1]` output to a `real [1 1]` input.

Does anybody know, in general, what negative indices mean for datatype size?

Answer (score 1):

This is explained @ https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.1.0/en_US/scicos_model.html :

*in*

A vector specifying the number and size of the first dimension of regular input ports indexed from top to bottom of the block. If no input port exist in==[]. The size can be negative, equal to zero or positive :

- If a size is less than zero, the compiler will try to find the appropriate size.
- If a size is equal to zero, the compiler will affect this dimension by added all positive size
  found in that vector
- If a size is greater than zero, then the size is explicitly given.